# Send a Fetch response to a parameter

Tags: javascript

How can I get a variable in the parameter within a JavaScript function, and then get a Fetch request to send it to the parameter?
This is my current code:

```
//The Function
function spotifyGet(method, variable) {
  var authorisationRequest = 'Bearer ' + spotifyAccessToken.access_token;
  console.log('Authorisation Request:' + authorisationRequest);
  var apiRequest = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/" + method

  fetch(apiRequest, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": authorisationRequest
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => variable = response) //The variable here isn't the parameter
}

//Calling the function
var sampleVar = {}
spotifyGet('me', sampleVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass "references to variables". You can however pass a function that will get called with the new value, then that function has access to the variable and can change it:

```
  function spotifyGet(method, callback) {     
   /*...*/.then(response => callback(response));
  }

  var sampleVar = {}
  spotifyGet('me', r => sampleVar = r);
```

Note: As that callback is asynchronous, further accesses of `sampleVar` might or might not return the actual results based on *when* you access it and *wether* `spotifyGet` was done. In most cases that is not wanted, and `sampleVar` should be a promise instead that resolves to the wanted value.

Comment: ```function spotifyGet(method, variable) {
  var authorisationRequest = 'Bearer ' + spotifyAccessToken.access_token;
  console.log('Authorisation Request:' + authorisationRequest);
  var apiRequest = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/" + method

  fetch(apiRequest, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": authorisationRequest
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => variable(response))
}

var sampleVar = {}
spotifyGet('me', r => sampleVar = r)``` Doesn't work. Something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "doesnt work" is not a problem description. *What* doesnt work?

Comment: Oh never mind, it works! Problem was I changed callback but not 'variable'. Thanks!